# Cambiar de mayúsculas a minúsculas una columna en rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Quisiera cambiar una comlumna de un dataframe mayusculas a minusculas pero no encuentro :c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

encontre la funcion  tolower() pero me convierte toda mi columna como un vector

Comment: Esto `df$DPA_MINUSCULA <- tolower(df$DPA_DESPRO)` debería resolverlo

Comment: Y de paso, bienvenida Sheyla Barrera a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.